# What is dollar sign syntax in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, intrinsics, typescript-utility

I was trying to explore TypeScript intrinsic `Capitalize` utility type and found the description of how it's implemented - it looks like this

```
type Capitalize<S extends string> = S extends `${infer C}${infer $S}`
  ? `${Uppercase<C>}${$S}`
  : never;
```

I can't quite get two things from this code:

- How does TS understand that `${infer C}` is the first letter?
- What is this `$S` syntax?

---

Small update.

My question wasn't exactly correct, the code above is not how `Capitalize` type is implement in TS, it's from github [proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42334). Some utility types in TS are implemented *intrinsicly*, which means they don't exactly use the types but rather JavaScript string runtime functions. It happens due to TypeScript overflows, so far TS doesn't support long iterations very well.

Regarding `${infer C}${infer $S}` it's not explained directly why `C` type stores first letter in [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), but I guess it's just a default behavior for TS when it has not enough references on how to split the word.

Let's check this example

```
type WordPart<S extends string> = S extends `${infer C}${infer R}`
  ? `${C}`
  : never;
type Part = WordPart<'hello'>;
```

The result `Part` type will be `'h'` cause it's not clear how to split the word. At the same time if we change `${infer C}${infer R}` to `${infer C}l${infer R}` we get `'he'` as a result type, so the TypeScript found the first matching `l` and split the word there, the remaining inferred `R` type would contain `lo` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does TS understand that ${infer C} is the first letter?

That is a string literal variable
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

> What is this $S syntax?

That belongs to a name